# Dropzone function is not working under jQuery in Mac OS

Tags: php, jquery, dropzone

I am using dropZone to drag and upload files but somehow it's not working. I am in Mac OS. I have given 777 permission to the uploaded folder, but still, it's not uploading. Here is my code:

```js
$(document).on('change','#type',function(){
      var type = $('#type').val();
      var course = $('#course').val();
      alert(type); alert(course);
      if(type != "" && course!= ""){
        $('#file_upload').show();
        Dropzone.options.dropzoneForm = {
            paramName: "uploadMultiple",
            maxFilesize: 5,
            dictDefaultMessage: "<strong>Drop files here or click to upload. </strong></br>",
            acceptedFiles: type,
            renameFile: 'course',
            url: "../files/course/"+course+"/",
            init: function () {
              this.on("complete", function (file) {
                if (this.getUploadingFiles().length === 0 && this.getQueuedFiles().length === 0) {
                  alert('File Uploaded');
                }
              });
            }
        };
      } else {
        $('#file_upload').hide();
      }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src ="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.4.0/dropzone.js"></script>
<select type="text" class="form-control" id="course" required>
      <option value="" selected disabled>Select Course</option>
      <option value="1">Development</option>
</select>

<select type="text" class="form-control" id="type" required>
      <option value="" selected disabled>Select File Type</option>
      <option value="application/pdf">PDF</option>
</select>
          
<div id="file_upload">          
  <form action="#" class="dropzone" id="dropzoneForm">
   <div class="fallback">
        <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
     </div>
 </form>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you have issue of `: Dropzone is not defined"`

Comment: I don't think so as I am getting the proper view. And if dropzone is not defined I would have to get some error in the console

Comment: I am running your snippet and getting this

Comment: please use `<script src ="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.4.0/dropzone.js"></script> `

Comment: "*Its not uploading*" ... are you saying the javascript is not firing off to send the files, or that php is failing to handle the files received? And if its php giving the error, why not include the PHP code. What you have suggests its javascript trying to save a file on the server (which is impossible).